# On a web page, embed stream of images from a particular hastag on social networks

Tags: web-services, social-networks

Please suggest services or server software, free or paid, that allows me to create an embeddable stream with the latest photos.

The stream should be created from photos and videos people publish in social networks with an hashtag. Ideally should cover as many networks as possible from this list:

- Twitter
- Instagram
- Flickr
- Vine
- Youtube
- Facebook
- Google+

Please note that this service's APIs are changing. I need something that works now.

This stream will be embed in a public web page.